# Receiver in Android generate a system popup

Tags: java, android

I have a Receiver in AndroidManifest, but he generate a popup with information about this, somehting like:

> "Received intent: intent {act=.com.mypacked bla bla
>   bla.NotifivationReceiver(has exras) bla bla bla"

It is impossible to not show up this system popup ?

No error in log, no crashes, and receiver works, but the only problem is that this popup covers the entire application screen, it appears only once when it receives information for the first time

Comment: please explain better your question, post more info as code , log error if exist. It's unclear what are you asking

Comment: as "popup" you mean Toast?

Comment: maybe this is toast, but on 80% screen

Comment: post code of your broadcast receiver